# How to resolve "no connection tracking support in the kernel" in Vuurmuur?

Tags: iptables, kernel-modules, firewall, ip-conntrack

So I'm trying to get Vuurmuur installed on a headless linux box that I've been using as a home router. So far, I've been using iptables but wanted to switch to  using something more convenient/easier to use.

**SERVER SETUP**

I'm running:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Xenial
4.4.0-97-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**VUURMUUR SETUP**

Vuurmuur doesn't have a debian package maintainer so I added this entry to my apt sources:

```
deb ftp://ftp.vuurmuur.org/ubuntu/ raring main
```

Do an apt-get update, install vuurmuur and things look ok BUT when I try to run vuurmuur this happens:

```
# vuurmuur
Error: checking for iptables-capabilities failed. Please see error.log.
```

I checked the documentation here: https://www.vuurmuur.org/trac/wiki/Faq
and that suggests that iptables or conntrack is not setup correctly

For completeness, this is the error in the error log:

```
01/04/2018 13:57:18 : PID 1866  : vuurmuur      : Error (-1): no connection tracking support in the kernel (in: check_iptcaps:402).
```

I did a lsmod for iptables and conntrack and they both seem to be there:

```
# lsmod | egrep "iptable|conntr"
nf_conntrack_netlink    40960  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink,nfnetlink_queue
iptable_mangle         16384  0
xt_conntrack           16384  2
iptable_filter         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  3
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_conntrack          106496  9 xt_helper,nf_nat,xt_state,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_connmark,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  20 xt_mark,xt_helper,xt_length,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_NFQUEUE,xt_limit,xt_state,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,xt_mac,xt_nat,iptable_filter,xt_CLASSIFY,xt_TCPMSS,xt_connmark,ipt_REJECT,xt_REDIRECT,iptable_mangle
```

**WHAT AM I MISSING?**

I've seen some other posts that the way conntrack is enabled has changed in the past so I'm wondering if between Raring and Xenial, the method to check for iptables/conntrack changed but vuurmuur hasn't been updated yet.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out their are two options:

**Option 1**

Run the vuurmuur command with the below option:

```
-t
```

**Option 2 (what I did)**

Use the 0.8rc5 version from the Vuurmuur website and I was able to start Vuurmuur.